# Show the names of employees of Company1 having salary greater than every employee of Company2 (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table Emp_company which has many columns and one of them is Salary. I need to know how to compare the Salaries of the employees from Company1 to the salaries of employees from Company2. Please help me if you can.

Comment: This isn't enough information to go off of.  Does Company 1 and Company 2 have separate tables, or is all the data in the same table?

Comment: Table names? Field Names? Table structure?

Comment: Company1 and Company2 are a part of column "Cname" of the same table. Sorry about that.

Comment: Table Name Emp_company. Field Names EName,Cname,Salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from Company1 WHERE Company1.Salary > (Select Max(company2.salary) from company2)
```

Solution for Sourav:
TRY this :

```
Select * from Company WHERE Salary > (Select salary from company WHERE cname = 'Company2' ORDER by salary desc LIMIT 1) AND cname = 'company1'
```

Comment: `of` isn't valid syntax

Comment: Company1 and Company2 are not Different fields. They come under the Field Cname.

Comment: The Field name is Cname and it holds values Company1 and Company2.

Comment: Okay !! Wait 4 a while

Comment: It Worked! Can you explain the query to me? I do not fully understand it.

Comment: I just explain it in a line
1) I just found out the max salary from those whose cname=company2
2) Then found greater then of it from those whose cname=company1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max of Company2 salaries like this:

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM company_table WHERE cname="company2";
```

...then get that parameter and find those at company1 who earn more:

```
SELECT * FROM company_table WHERE cname="company1" AND salary > x;
```

...where `x` is the result of the first query.

EDIT: edited to use same table for both companies, as mentioned by poster in the comments

EDIT: the full query all on one line:

```
SELECT * FROM company_table WHERE cname="company1" AND salary > (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM company_table WHERE cname="company2");
```

Comment: Just thought I'd answer in a modular way - the user could use subqueries but I thought the code would be easier to see if I separated them

Comment: I don't think that's easier at all. The subquery version is pretty darn straightforward. Now you have two queries and need some system to move the result of A to query B.

Comment: Exactly. How do I move the result of the first query to the second query?

Comment: I've updated it. At first I was assuming you were running it from a shell, just as a one-time query.

Comment: The Edited Query will work if:
SELECT * FROM company_table WHERE cname="company1" AND salary > (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM company_table WHERE cname="company2");